# Randomize frames with no repeats with html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Super noob question here. I have the code below from an as3 project below where frame numbers are randomized then clicking a sprite (next) will move to the next random frame. I am having trouble figuring out what else I need to do to convert it to javascript. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction? TIA!

```
var sortedNumbers:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 1; i < 21; i++)
{
    sortedNumbers.push(i);
 }
var unsortedNumbers:Array = sortedNumbers.slice();

while(sortedNumbers.join() == unsortedNumbers.join())
{
    unsortedNumbers.sort(function (a:int, b:int):int { return Math.random() > .5 ? -1 : 1; });
}

this.start.addEventListener("click", f_nextRE.bind(this));

function f_nextRE() {
        if(index == 20) {
    gotoAndStop (22);
    }
    else {
    gotoAndStop (unsortedNumbers [index] + 1);
    index +=1;  
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a valid `javascript` code

Comment: Yes... It is actionscript 3. I am very new at javascript and was looking for some help. converting this. or getting pointed in the right direction to where I can learn how to randomize a string of numbers then pull from them to play frames from an HTML5 canvas in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

So it took me a few days but I found my answer (a combination of several sources many on this site)... Posting it here to help others...

```
//create array
var shuffledFrames = [];
//fill array
for (var i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
   shuffledFrames.push(i);
}
//shuffle array 
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
   }
}
//run shuffle function
shuffle(shuffledFrames);
//function to call next random frame then repeat when reaching the end. 
function f_next()
{
    if (shown == 1){
        if (nextF == 35) {
            nextF = 0;
            }
        else {
        nextF += 1;
        }
    this.gotoAndStop (shuffledFrames [nextF]);
    }
}
```